# 7.zip Extract Only Updated Files

Tags: python, linux, windows

I have .zip file which has around 40,000 files.

Questions:

1. For the first it takes time to extract, fine no problem, but for the 2nd run should only extract files that are found to be changed than in zip. Just want to make extraction faster.
2. Is there any option in 7z.exe that provides multithreading extraction.
3. Any other python based code/executable?
4. Same in linux based `/usr/bin/unzip` which is quite faster. It does the whole job in around 20-22sec, though it has -o option to overwrite. Any windows based solution which is equivalent to /usr/bin/unzip ?

What I have tried till -

1. python:

   ````
       pkg.extractall(destination)```
   ````
2. executables:

   `powershell.exe Expand-Archive src.zip -DestinationPath dest_path`
   `7z x "src.zip" -o"dest" -aoa`

All above defined approaches are taking a lot of time.

Any solution from some good guy is appreciated.

Please let me you if things are unclear.

Thanks